# Running razor with spamassassin

Tags: spamassassin, razor

To run razor with spamassassin on a default installation, is it enough to install it or is there any extra configuration to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable it in Spamassassin, too:

```
loadplugin Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::Razor2
```

That's probably by default commented out in `/etc/mail/spamassassin/v310.pre` or likewise.